# Without jQuery, create a new element AFTER a specifc element and then "MOVE" some other elements on the page into it with JAVASCRIPT only

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have the following jQuery code to inject an element after another element and then MOVE some elements into it. I wasn't able to find any clear vanilla js functions do this as most people were suggesting insertBefore or insertAdjacentElement but none of them work in the chrome console. I'm trying to just do this in vanilla js.

```
jQuery('<div id="jsinjected"><i class="field-name-title"></i></div>').insertAfter('.field-name-body');
jQuery('.group-header .field-name-title ~ .field').appendTo('#jsinjected');
```

Comment: Can you post code for how you tried `insertBefore`/`insertAdjacentElement`?. I'm not sure why they wouldn't work.

Comment: When doing an insertBefore I'm getting an "is not a function" error. See: http://prntscr.com/gvok6i -- not sure what im doing wrong. I'd imagine these are native js functions within the browser.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, you would need to choose one(like maybe `b[0]`) and call the methods on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```js
    const after = document.getElementById("element");
    const move = document.getElementById("move");
    const parent = after.parentNode;
    const tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.innerHTML = 
      `<div id="jsinjected"><i class="field-name-title">injected</i></div>`;
    const newElement = tmp.firstElementChild;
    var next = after.nextSibling;
    if(next === null){
      next = document.createTextNode(" ");
      parent.appendChild(next);
    }
    parent.insertBefore(newElement, next);
    newElement.appendChild(move);
```

```html
   <div><div id="move">move this</div>
    <div id="element">after</div></div>
```